# How do I use client certificates for authentication against Hono?

Tags: eclipse-hono

Where do I best start if I want to use authentication with client certificates in Hono? In the User Guide is a short description but a this does not show all required steps in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are able to connect to the respective protocol adapter with TLS 
(see the [Admin Guide](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/admin-guide/secure_communication/#using-openssl) for configuration). [Here](https://blog.bosch-si.com/developer/x-509-based-device-authentication-in-eclipse-hono/) is an article, that 
provides a complete walk-through guide for all required steps.

Additionally you can use and adapt the script for the creation of demo certificates in the Hono repository. More information can be found in the user guide of the protocol adapters ([MQTT](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/user-guide/mqtt-adapter/#authentication), [HTTP](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/user-guide/http-adapter/#device-authentication)).